# Memory leaks or normal for Android apps?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a really memory hungry app which is really not what I was going for. On average it sits around 90Mb and goes between that and 120Mb. Which is weird because the other night it was only hogging around 40Mb which is obviously more acceptable.
My first problem arrives when I simply run the app. The second problem is when I scroll through my ListView I can see the memory getting filled up large chunks at a time. 
SOoo now I am off hunting memory leaks. 
I started at a Heap Dump with the new Android Studio feature/button 'Dump Java Heap'.
So on displaying all the content of the Heap Dump I noticed really large numbers every now and then ESPECIALLY when it comes to LinkedHashMaps and HashMaps.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmaFA.png]

For the amount of work the app does before getting to the ListView it should really not have that amount of memory already used(I Believe) unless it comes standard with every app which I doubt.

Looking at this picture, how do I know which is real memory leaks and how do I find them from here on?

Ok soo I would insert the first 2 functions called right before my ListView will display.

Keep in mind that all my images are loaded with picasso from the internal storage and because it's pretty fast I switched of memory caching also.

This function prepares the adapter and also sends the objectID so that the new intent can fetch the data from the SQLite DB by itself.

```
public void DisplayList(final List<ListData> DL)
{

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ParseAdapter(this,DL);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Parse_list);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    String food = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    //setContentView(R.layout.deal_showcase);

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Deal_Showcase.class);

                    i.putExtra("objectid",DL.get(position).getObjectID());
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(this,DL.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            }

    );
}

//Adapter class
public class ParseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListData>
{

ParseAdapter(Context context, List<ListData> adapResource) {
    super(context, R.layout.parse_list_layout, adapResource);
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parse_list_layout, parent, false);

    //PLease note that after implementing a ViewHolder is did not really do anything for me
    //Also the ViewHolder implementation is not here at the moment but this is the version of           //the code right before the ViewHolder got implemented.
        String singleItem = getItem(position).getName();
        TextView rText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.pName);

        TextView yText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.pDistance);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        rText.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        yText.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).getDistance()));
        Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load("file://"+getItem(position).getArt_work_uri())
                .resize(200,200)
                .into(image);

        return customView;
    }

}
```

CODE EDIT 1:

```
public class ParseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DealListData>
{
    //Inner static class ViewHolder
    static class ViewHolder
    {
    TextView Distance;
    TextView DealName;
    ImageView image;
}


ParseAdapter(Context context, List<DealListData> adapResource) {
    super(context, R.layout.parse_list_layout, adapResource);
}
    View convertView;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;



        if (convertView==null)
        {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parse_list_layout, parent, false);
            //ViewHolder holder setup
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.DealName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pName);
            holder.Distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pDistance);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            //Store the holder in the view
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            //Get the holder if it already exists
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        holder.DealName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        holder.Distance.setText(Integer.toString(getItem(position).getDistance()));
        Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load("file://"+getItem(position).getArt_work_uri())
                //.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE )
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .resize(200,200)
                .into(holder.image);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: In eclipse you had a button called "leak suspects" it is probably around in android studio too, what does that tell you?

Comment: I will have a look into that asap!

Comment: See my answer below. I think I found your issue.

Comment: @JohanShogun I am not sure if you are maybe refering to the "start allocation tracking" button thats just below the Dump heap button. Thing is theres only 3 buttons..the other one is a Garbage Collector button.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMemoryAnalyzer/article.html if you don't have something like it in android studio you can open up the head dump file in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally consider leaks to be memory that *should* be freed but *isn't*, and it's hard for outsiders to know what falls into that category for your app.  For your case, if you look near the top of your list, you'll see Picasso's LruCache.  Picasso's cache contains a LinkedHashMap, which contains a bunch of Entries (the things immediately above the LruCache), which in this case contains a bunch of bitmaps.

By default, Picasso will use up to 1/8th of your *max* memory for a cache, so you don't keep hitting the disk.  On a large device, your app may have a couple hundred MB, so this can be fairly large.  This is generally desirable, because it keeps your app feeling fast.  You *might* consider it a leak, because it's "wasting" memory and it won't go away, but it's intended.

---

So!  On to the tool.

If you click on one of the entries in the class list on the left, and look at the pane to the right, you'll see a list of instances of that type.  Click on one.  On the bottom pane, you'll see *why* that object is in memory.  If you keep expanding things, you'll generally find code you recognize (e.g. you'll find the View that is using the bitmap, or an LruCache entry for Picasso).  Hopefully you don't see an Activity that isn't on screen, because that would generally imply a bad leak.

The chain of references at the bottom shows you the *shortest* path to the "GC root" (the ultimate reason it's in memory, e.g. a Thread or static variable).  Usually this is the most relevant, but unfortunately not always.  There may be other reasons something is kept in memory, e.g. it might be in a cache *and* currently in use by a view.  So it's useful, but not *as* useful as what you can get with [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), which shows you *all* paths, and has much more powerful query tools and whatnot.  Hopefully the tools team will add more capabilities eventually, this feature kinda feels like a minimum viable release.

As an example, here's an app I work on, where I hold onto a cache in my Application which Picasso is using.  If you do something similar, and you really want to free memory when the user leaves your app, you can clear the cache when you get e.g. [TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN):
[image: Example heap dump]

Comment: It seems you don't have issues with bitmaps. I myself implemented similar cache + ref counting for native image data, which is what Picasso is doing as it seems. You also cannot replace it with your own code easily because it (a) its quite some coding (b) it looks mature piece of software that probably don't have serious memory leaks. Let's do it step by step. Tell me, did you see any difference with the list change I proposed?

Comment: @Umka: Well not anything really significant. However the app does feel a bit smoother and also the Garbage collector seems to do its job better now for some reason!

Comment: @Groxx: Thanks for that solid explanation. Ive noticed however that even before my ListView launches OR any of its resources gets loaded that the APP just jumps to 80Mg +.

Comment: @Groxx: How do I let my app clear the Cache on exit though?

Answer (score 0):

Lists are both tricky in android and ios. The main principle is to keep in memory only what is currently visible. It is a chance you did something wrong with your list. Would be nice to show your list code here.

It seems that your getView() method misses important part. Should be something like this:

```
        View customView;

        if (convertView != null) {
            customView = convertView;
        } else {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parse_list_layout, parent, false);
        }
```

In your code you never reuse already existing list items. Consumed memory is growing as you scroll through the list.

Another issue particularly with android is garbage collecting for native data, such as images data that you use in your app. If you have your list items with images then most probably you have also got this case too.

Comment: Please let me know if you need anything else. I have seen apps with way more going on then this app and the entire device only had 512Mb. So I am sure that I am doing something very wrong here.

Comment: Your getView() method looks suspicious. Will modify my answer.

Comment: I have updated by post with a second Code space. Check the block below my original code for the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getView()` method is not recycling the views and every time will inflate a new item, approximately every inflate process takes around 1.2KB 
recycle the views to save memory.

also you might want to check this video to grasp a better idea of Google I/O:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Something else could cause a memory leakage is when you use large size images and will exceed the memory budget and eventually crash, make sure to optimize the images

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.
Ok soo let me just get something straight about Picasso. If it downloads the picture...does it sit in RAM and gets re sized in RAM. If the pic is quite big but its retrieved locally will the Re-Sizing cause it to maybe sit in RAM and not get removed? If soo then that might definitely be my problem.
What bothers me is the moment the apps just loads the basics without even starting to load the ListView it jumps too 80Mg+